# Pros and cons of casting vs. providing a method that returns the required type (Java)

Tags: java, casting

I'm doing a bit of playing about to learn a framework I'm contributing to, and an interesting question came up. **EDIT:** *I'm doing some basic filters in the Okapi Framework, as described in [this guide](http://okapi.opentag.com/devguide/gettingstarted.html), note that the filter must return different event types to be useful, and that resources must be used by reference (as the same resource may be used in other filters later)*. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
    while (filter.hasNext()) {
        Event event = filter.next();
        if (event.isTextUnit()) {
            TextUnit tu = (TextUnit)event.getResource();
            if (tu.isTranslatable()) {
                //do something with it
            }
        }
    }
```

Note the cast of the resource to a TextUnit object on line 4. This works, I know it's a TextUnit because events that are `isTextUnit()` will always have a TextUnit resource. However, an alternative would be to add an `asTextUnit()` method to the IResource interface that returns the event as a TextUnit (as well as equivalent methods for each common resource type), so that the line would become:

```
            TextUnit tu = event.getResource().asTextUnit;
```

Another approach might be providing a static casting method in TextUnit itself, along the lines of:

```
            TextUnit tu = TextUnit.fromResource(event.getResource());
```

**My question is:** what are some arguments for doing it one way or the other? Are there performance differences?

The main advantage I can think of with `asTextUnit()` (or `.fromResource`) is that more appropriate exceptions could be thrown if someone tries to get a resource as the wrong type (i.e. with a message like `"Cannot get this RawDocument type resource as a TextUnit - use asRawDocument()"` or `"The resource is not a TextUnit"`).

The main disadvantages I can think of with `.asTextUnit()` is that each resource type would then have to implement all the methods (most of which will just throw an exception), and if another major resource type is added there would be some refactoring to add the new method to every resource type (although there's no reason the `.asSomething()` methods would have to be defined for every possible type, the less common resources could just be cast, although this would lead to inconsistency of approach). This wouldn't be a problem with `.fromResource()` since it's just one method per type, and could be added or not per type depending on preference.

Comment: the performance characteristics of each approach are for all practical purposes the same.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy would that hold for running a large number of documents through a pipeline with several filters like this (as far as how long the filter would take to run)?

Comment: doing casting, introduces one opcode CAST to the set of instructions executed. doing something like .asTextUnit() adds on top of that a ALOAD_0, INVOKEVIRTUAL and ARETURN opcodes. so doing the cast is theoretically faster. But compared to any possible processing you do for each document, you will not be able to measure the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the aim is to test an object's type and cast it, then I don't see any value in creating / using custom `isXyz` and `asXyz` methods.  You just end up with a bunch of extra methods that make little difference to code readability.

Re: your point about appropriate exception messages, I would say that it is most likely not worth it.  It is reasonable to assume that not having a `TextUnit` when a `TextUnit` is expected is symptom of a bug somewhere.  IMO, it is not worthwhile trying to provide "user friendly" diagnostics for bugs.  The person that the information is aimed at is a Java programmer, and for that person the default message and stacktrace for a regular ClassCastException (and the source code) provides all of the information required.  (Translating it into pretty language adds no real value.)

On the flip-side, the performance differences between the two forms are not likely to be significant.  But consider this:

```
    if (x instanceof Y) {
        ((Y) x).someYMethod();
    }
```

versus

```
    if (x.isY()) {
        x.asY().someYMethod();
    }

    boolean isY(X x) { return x instanceof Y; }
    Y asY(X x) { return (Y) x; }
```

The optimizer *might* be able to do a better job of the first compared with the second.

- It might not inline the method calls in the second case, especially if it is changed to use `instanceof` and throw a custom exception.
- It is less likely to figure out that only one type test is really required in the second case.  (It might not in the first case either ... but it is more likely to.)

But either way, the performance difference is going to be small.

---

Summary, the fancy methods are not really worth the effort, though they don't do any real harm.

---

Now if the `isXyz` or `asXyz` methods were testing the state of the object (not just the object's Java type), or if the `asXyz` was  returning a wrapper, then the answers would be different ...

Answer (score 2):

You could also just go

```
if (event instanceof TextUnit) {
    // ...
}
```

and save yourself the trouble.

To answer your question regarding whether to go `asTextUnit()` vs. `TextUnit.fromResource`, the performance difference would depend upon how you actually implement these methods.

In the case of the static converter you would have a to create and return a new object of type `TextUnit`. However, in the case of the member function you could simply return `this` casted or you could create an return a new object - depends upon your use case.

Either ways, seems like `instanceof` is probably the cleanest way here.

Comment: event is not a TextUnit. event is an Event, and it has a resource attached to it of type TextUnit.

Comment: Creating a new TextUnit is not an option since the resource attached to the event needs to persist for later use. As far as implementation, I think `asTextUnit()` would be the most intensive since it would try the cast, catch an exception if thrown, and throw a new exception with an appropriate method. `TextUnit.fromResource()` would require no casting (just return `this`), but there's still a method call there so a bit of overhead compared with a straight cast (Note: I don't know the inner workings of casting, so maybe there's overhead in that I'm not considering).

Answer (score 2):

What if your filter were extended - or wrapped - to return only text unit events?  In fact, what if it returned only the resources of text unit events?  Then your loop would be much simpler.  I would think the clean way to do this would be a second filter, which simply returned just the text unit events, followed by, let's say, an Extractor, which returned the properly cast resource.

Comment: That wouldn't work, since filters process documents that will have (at minimum) a START_DOCUMENT and an END_DOCUMENT event, as well as a number of other events in between (which depend on the input document).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a common base class, you can have a single asXMethod there for every derived class, and needn't refactor all derived classes:

```
abstract class Base {
   A asA () { throw new InstantiationException ("not an A"); }
   B asB () { throw new InstantiationException ("not an B"); }
   C asC () { throw new InstantiationException ("not an C"); }
   // much more ...
}

class A extends Base {
   A asA () { /* hard work */ return new A (); }  
   // no asB, asC requiered
}

class B extends Base {
   B asB () { /* hard work */ return new B (); }  
   // no asA, asC required
}
// and so on.
```

looks pretty clever. For a new Class N, just add a new Method to Base, and all derived classes get it. Just N needs to implement asN.

But it smells.

Why should a B have a method asA if it will always fail? That's not a good design. Exceptions in the generator are cheap, if they aren't triggered. Only thrown exceptions might be costly.

Comment: If a base type and all its derivatives are supposed to have mutable semantics, that would imply that the concept of reference equality would be meaningful and there may not be much for an `AsB` to do without violating that. If, however, the type has immutable semantics and reference equality is not meaningful, then `AsB` could meaningfully return something other than `this`. Even if it's not possible for a single class to inherit from immutable types `A` and `B`, that would not prevent one class from providing useful implementations of `AsA` and `AsB`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are differences. Creating new immutable elements is better then casting. Pass all serializable data (non transient or computable data) to a Builder and build appropriate class.